# Ruby String to access an object attribute

Tags: ruby

I have a text file (objects.txt) which contains Objects and its attributes.
The content of the file is something like:

`Object.attribute = "data"`

On a different file, I am Loading the objects.txt file and if I type:

`puts object.attribute`  it prints out `data`

The issue comes when I am trying to access the object and/or the attribute with a string. What I am doing is:

`var = "object"  +    "."  + "access"
puts var`

It prints out `object.access` and not the content of it `"data"`.

I have already tried with `instance_variable_get` and it works, but I have to modify the object.txt and append an `@` at the beginning to make it an instance variable, but I cannot do this, because I am not the owner of the object.txt file.

As a workaround I can parse the object.txt file and get the data that I need but I don't want to do this, as I want take advantage of what is already there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to access the object via a string, if you've loaded your objects.txt file and have access to it?

Comment: Because basically I need to verify that what is on object.txt is correct, and I have thousands of attributes in object.txt, and since the data is not in order, I am generating the String in my ruby file to get its value and compare to the expected value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, puts is correctly spitting out "object.access" because you are creating that string exactly.

In order to evaluate a string as if it were ruby code, you need to use `eval()`

eg:

```
var = "object"  +    "."  + "access"
puts eval(var)
=> "data"
```

Be aware that doing this is quite dangerous if you are evaluating anything that potentially comes from another user.

Comment: I tried with eval before, but I don't know why it didn't work... anyways this is exactly what i need. Thank you